# cardview not showing cornerRadius and elevation

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I created a card view in a recycler view and my codes work well but the problem now is that the cardview does not show the rounded edges and elevation at runtime but it shows in the design codes. my codes are shown blow

**activity_main**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Controller.MainActivity">

    <uk.co.markormesher.android_fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:buttonIcon="@drawable/ic_add_group"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/groupListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my **card_view.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/groupCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Trips"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I do not know what I have done wrong

Comment: set background color to cardview. You set set same color which you are using for the page.

Comment: i found my error. I was setting background color instead of cardbackgroundcolor

Answer (score 3):

Anyone could encounter this issue and the solution is very simple and caused by a mistake.there's a difference between `backgroundColor` and `cardbackgroundColor`. use `setcardbackgroundColor` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

for main constraint, and set

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
```

to cardview, np